# How to redirect URL in Apache Tomcat 7?

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, dns, server.xml

I don't have much knowledge about dns the IT-support team has given a dns to me which looks like ::

```
 https://abc.xyz.com:8443/web
```

It is accessible , as you can see port number is suffixed to url name.
Now i have to add redirection to this url so as if anyone uses

`https://abc.xyz.com` 
he should be redirected to

```
https://abc.xyz.com:8443/web
```

How to achieve this , can anyone suggest ?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: @dusan.bajic :: yes i have it

Answer (score 0):

It's very Simple to Proceed.

Step 1 : Make your https default port to 443

Open **Sever.xml** file and change the port **8443** to **443**.

Step 2 : Stop your Running tomcat server

Remove all files inside **\webapp** folder except web.war file.

Rename **web.war** into **root.war**.

Now Start the Tomcat server and access your url- https://abc.xyz.com

Enjoy : )

Comment: Thanks for your help , actually i have done the same previously but actually there are other applications which run in same container for this reason i can't name it to root.war.